# Integration of ng2-webcam in angular4 angular-cli based app Failed to compile

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have created a brand new Angular4 application using angular-cli. After that I have integrated ng2-webcam using npm install. Now if I add this ng2-webcam dependancy in app.module.ts

```
import { WebCamComponent } from 'ng2-webcam';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WebCamComponent
  ],
 ....
})
export class AppModule { }
```

On `ng serve` it fails to compile and throws the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./~/ng2-webcam/lib/fallback/jscam.swf
Module parse failed: f:\projects\edu\hops\webcam\node_modules\ng2-webcam\lib\fallback\jscam.swf Unexpected character '' (1:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./~/ng2-webcam/index.ts 4:0-34
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

It would be appreciated if some one help me how to resolve this? How to include loader?

Comment: It seems like you're not the only one seeing this: https://gitter.im/angular/angular-cli?at=5883db27d43728124e88dd7e. Have you tried raising an issue with the package maintainers?

Comment: Please elaborate me how to resolve this?